# Any books about Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-literature

Thanks for any link/author+title. I prefer max. 2 years to the past if possible. If you know about some book that will be published in the near future, you can mention it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new book called Bitcoin Step by Step is out on Kindle.


[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A1CUQQU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A1CUQQU)

It will get users started safe and secure in the Bitcoin market place.  It takes them screen by screen 
- on how to set up a wallet securely
- Funding an account
- sending / receiving BTC
- Extracting BTC to currency
- Where they can spend BTC
- How they can earn BTC

Answer (score 7):

Bitcoin was barely around 2 years ago;).

Currently to my knowledge the closest thing to a Bitcoin book is [my master thesis on Bitcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=88149.0). It focuses on analysing the security of Bitcoin software and the ecosystem, but a lot of people find it to be a good read even for beginners. It is in English, but wasn't published anywhere but a couple prints for my studies and online.

Comment: It was one of the first things i read of substance on BTC...It gave the first window into the technology..the other books are very much beginners guides for Mum & Dad

Comment: Hello. Is there any hope to have it converted to ePub format for easy reading on e-ink or any other small screen devices? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dakatine It was written in Word, so I'm not sure if it would be a painless and straightforward process to convert it to such a format without devoting a lot of effort into it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're into more of the programmatic side of Bitcoin check out "[Mastering Bitcoin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449374042)" coming out soon from O'Reily Media.

You can get the "raw and unedited" version for free, just search for it on Google. (it's legal and downloadable from O'Reily Media)

Answer (score 3):

Peter Surda is writing a book which if I understand correctly, will explain the foundations of money and how they relate to Bitcoin.

In addition, coindl.com lists several eBooks, some of them are about Bitcoin. Examples:

- "A Beginner's Guide To Bitcoin And Bitcoin Services" by Trace Mayer,
  J.D.
- "A Lawyer's Take On Bitcoin And Taxes" by Trace Mayer,
  J.D.
- "You Can Learn Bitcoin" by David R. Sterry.
- "Introduction to Bitcoin Mining: A Guide for Gamers, Geeks and Everyone Else" by David R. Sterry.
- "Bitcoin - What It Is and Why It Matters" by Anthony Freeman.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Learn Bitcoin

- https://www.coindl.com/page/item/391

There are a couple others:

- https://www.coindl.com/page/category/ebooks

Answer (score 1):

Le Bitcoin Book (in French) written by Pierre Noizat is available here:
http://www.lulu.com/shop/pierre-noizat/bitcoin-book/paperback/product-20477450.html

Published under creative commons license.

Answer (score 1):

Travis Batterson recently wrote a book called *Bitcoin: A Basic Explanation of Everything*. I know it's available on Kindle [here](https://sites.google.com/site/travisbatterson/) and you can order physical copies on the website [basicbitcoin.com](http://basicbitcoin.com). The book gives a good cover of all things Bitcoin and for what it's worth isn't bad.

Answer (score 1):

What's the deal with Bitcoins is THE book to read to learn about bitcoins. On Amazon and at http://bitcoins.peopletested.com

Answer (score 0):

*Owning Bitcoin* covers Bitcoin in both theory and practice:

https://bitzuma.com/owning-bitcoin/

Topics include:

- Elliptic curve cryptography
- Hash funtions
- Network operation
- Script
- Advanced contracts
- Cold storage using Electrum

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more blog, a small eBook:
https://infopedia.io/revolution-of-money/

(Money and Payment systems of tomorrow)
Bitcoin rise with crypto industry story

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

*"The Wonderful World of Bitcoin and Other Inventions"*

by Penina and Zahava Shtauber

It's a kid's book, really fun and accessible.

[https://www.amazon.com/Wonderful-World-Bitcoin-Other-Inventions/dp/9659275749](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9659275749)